# Add a subpanel record to a SugarCRM account through REST API

Tags: rest, sugarcrm

Question: How do I create a subpanel record through the SugarCRM rest api endpoint for accounts?

Steps taken so far:

1. I've added a new package called, "transactionHistory" with a module named, "InvoiceHistory" using the SugarCRM studio.
2. I added a One to Many relationship to the Accounts module using studio.

I'm using NetSuite to push new invoices to the new module's record via the subpanel "create" option. Here's the code I'm using:

```
function createSugarTransaction(transaction, token) {
var url = 'https://crm.techsoft3d.com/rest/v10/Accounts/' + transaction.customer;
var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "OAuth-Token": token
};
var now = (new Date()).toISOString();
var body = {transactionHistory_InvoiceHistory:
    {
        create: [{
            name: transaction.docId,
            transaction_date_c: transaction.date,
            invoice_status_c: transaction.status,
            due_date_c: transaction.duedate,
            total_amount_c: transaction.total,
            amount_due_c: transaction.remaining,
            start_date_c: transaction.startdate,
            end_date_c: transaction.enddate
        }]
    }
};

var response = nlapiRequestURL(url, JSON.stringify(body), headers, 'PUT');
return response;
}
```

The transaction object has been validated and the json object within the `create: []` array has matching sugar fields (key) with the corresponding transaction object values.

When making the API call to sugar I'm successfully authenticated and have access to the custom module and accounts - so no problem there.  However, when the call is returned to `response` it's showing the following error:

`{"error":"no_method","error_message":"Could not find a route with 1 elements"}`

I'm unsure of what else is needed in order for the record to be created. According to sugar's help documentation and developer community this should work.  I'm using the basic information provided by sugarcrm support portal:

http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.6/API/Web_Services/Examples/v10/module_POST/

According to other blog posts within the developer community, it should be as simple as adding the subpanel name, followed by an array of fields under the "create" object... similar to this:

`var requestBody = { package_module:create[{name:value}]};`

My initial thinking of what's wrong is:
1. my package_module name isn't correct, but I'm unable to find it anywhere within the applicaiton or help documentation.
2. the request body isn't formatted properly, even though it's structure was copied from this article https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2014/02/28/sugarcrm-cookbook2/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So the subpanel record has already been created on its own first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the `createRelatedRecord` api endpoint

type {sugarurl}/rest/v10/help to see a list of endpoints to look through, most of which have documentation and examples

https://crm.techsoft3d.com/rest/v10/help

your API `url` should have the name of the link (relationship) you want, in addition to the values in the POST payload

https://crm.techsoft3d.com/rest/v10/Accounts/{transaction.customer}/link/accounts_transactionhistory  (or whatever your link's name is)

per the documentation for this endpoint, you just specify the field values in the payload

`{
    "first_name":"Bill",
    "last_name":"Edwards"
}`